# Python/selenium scraping links from website that is keep refreshing

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping, steam

I'm using ChatGPT to help me code a web scraper to scrape links from Steam. I am trying to get a full list of the webpage of all the indie games. The Steam indie list only has 12 games at a time unless I click on the more button. I realized that whenever I click the button the number at the end of the webpage change. so I made a code so that it would iterate a base URL with the number in the back to change so that I can keep scraping different lists. Here is the code

```
    import csv
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
from selenium.webdriver.common.action_chains import ActionChains
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

# Set up Chrome options for running in headless mode
chrome_options = Options()
chrome_options.add_argument("--headless")  # Enable headless mode

# Set up the Selenium webdriver with the specified options
driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=chrome_options)  # Replace with the path to your chromedriver executable

# Define the base URL
base_url = "https://store.steampowered.com/tags/en/Indie/?offset="

# Create a list to store the links and URLs
data = []

# Iterate over the website IDs
for website_id in range(12, 97, 12):
    url = base_url + str(website_id)
    driver.get(url)

    # Define the explicit wait with a maximum timeout of 10 seconds
    wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 10)

    # Scroll to the bottom of the page using JavaScript
    driver.execute_script("window.scrollTo(0, document.body.scrollHeight);")

    # Find all the parent elements that trigger the mouse hover interaction
    parent_elements = wait.until(EC.visibility_of_all_elements_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, '.salepreviewwidgets_TitleCtn_1F4bc')))

    # Clear the data list
    data.clear()

    # Iterate over the parent elements
    for parent_element in parent_elements:
        # Move the mouse cursor to the parent element to trigger the mouse hover action
        actions = ActionChains(driver)
        actions.move_to_element(parent_element).perform()

        # Find the child element (link) within the parent element
        link_element = parent_element.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, 'a')

        # Extract the link URL and add it to the data list
        link = link_element.get_attribute('href')
        data.append([link, url])

    # Save the data to the CSV file by appending to existing content
    output_filename = "links.csv"

    with open(output_filename, 'a', newline='') as csvfile:
        writer = csv.writer(csvfile)
        writer.writerows(data)  # Append the data to the file

    print("Data appended to", output_filename)

# Close the webdriver
driver.quit()``
```

But the result is weird. First, it seems like the code is not scraping all the links cause each iteration should have 12 links. Instead, it gets 3 or sometimes it gets 6. Also it seems the code is keep scraping the first page of the list. While the list is not completely the same but have similar game links. I am guessing this is because the first page of the list changes every time you visit the first page for the first time.

Comment: I'm not familiar with Steam, and not sure what your ultimate objective is, but have you considered alternative ways to obtain the information you're trying to collect?  some websites provide a free API to their data, so you wouldn't have to scrape it.  another alternative might be to use their search page with "Indie" as a search term.

Answer (score 0):

The problem here was scrolling to the bottom, which didn't trigger javascript to load the games info in sale section. Also range(12, 97, 12) starts with offset=12, so you get result that is added *after clicking Show More button*.
To get the code working, you need to scroll to sale section instead of bottom of page.
Optional changes are to:

- change condition for `for loop`
- remove scrolling to each item to get value
- get *name* and *url* of the game instead *link* and *url*
- declare data[] inside for loop
- use encoding while saving and other ...

```
import csv
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
from selenium.webdriver.common.action_chains import ActionChains
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

# Set up Chrome options for running in headless mode
chrome_options = Options()
chrome_options.add_argument("--headless")  # Enable headless mode

# Set up the Selenium webdriver with the specified options
driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=chrome_options)  # Replace with the path to your chromedriver executable
driver.maximize_window()

# actions moved here
actions = ActionChains(driver)
# Define the base URL
base_url = "https://store.steampowered.com/tags/en/Indie/?offset="

# Create a list to store the links and URLs
# data = []

start_page = 0
end_page = 8

# Iterate over the website IDs
for website_id in range(start_page*12, end_page*12+1, 12):
    url = base_url + str(website_id)
    driver.get(url)

    # Define the explicit wait with a maximum timeout of 10 seconds
    wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 10)

    # Scroll to the bottom of the page using JavaScript
    # driver.execute_script("window.scrollTo(0, document.body.scrollHeight);")

    # scroll to sale section
    sale_section = WebDriverWait(driver, 5).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.ID, 'SaleSection_93094')))
    actions.move_to_element(sale_section).perform()

    # Find all the parent elements that trigger the mouse hover interaction
    parent_elements = wait.until(EC.visibility_of_all_elements_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, '.salepreviewwidgets_TitleCtn_1F4bc')))

    # Clear the data list
    data = []
    # data.clear()

    # Iterate over the parent elements
    for parent_element in parent_elements:
        # Move the mouse cursor to the parent element to trigger the mouse hover action
        # actions = ActionChains(driver)
        # actions.move_to_element(parent_element).perform()

        # Extract the name and URL and add it to the data list
        name = parent_element.get_attribute('innerText')
        url = parent_element.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, 'a').get_attribute('href')

        data.append([name, url])

    # Save the data to the CSV file by appending to existing content
    output_filename = "links.csv"

    with open(output_filename, 'a', newline='', encoding='utf-8') as csvfile:
        writer = csv.writer(csvfile)
        writer.writerows(data)  # Append the data to the file

    print("Data appended to", output_filename)

# Close the webdriver
driver.quit()
```